# How to auto fill Text box in php (Similar to Facebook)

Tags: php, facebook, shopping-cart, autofill

What I am trying to do is to make something similar to what I see all the time on almost any website. The button that says Share to facebook. The goal for me is to let my guests share the item they are viewing in my store (Ran on prestashop) on their blog I run (Running on Oxwall).

The goal is for the button to not only link to a blog post submission webpage but to already have the subject line filled out with the item they are sharing's name and the blog post to display the information about the item. I would like to try and do all this using PHP. I am not sure how to go about doing it but I am sure that I could pass the value. Please note that I can mod BOTH the blog site and the shop as I run both and want to connect them.

As an extra bonus I am also running a forum using phpbb3 if I could do the same thing but onto that as well I would greatly thank you. I am trying to interlink everything into one big network. I know its not an easy task but I am sure there is an easy way to pass data onto the other site so that this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook a 2 tools to get items informations in the page, it parses the page looking for the most common tags and it uses OpenGraph.

You can also provide product informations in the head of your page (between head tags), then blog side, you retrieve only the  contents and parse it as XML.

I advise you to cache this data to avoid useless connections between websites and awful overloads while parsing.

You can use your own specifications, Open Graph or another standard, but i advise to use a standard.